# How to add GetFileFromPathAsync's Path in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I would like to share a file given by its filepath. After clicking Share charm it says: there was a problem with the data coming from my app. What is the right format for the filepath?

```
string filepath = "C:\Users\USER\Pictures\pic.png"; // bad format, unrecognized escape sequence
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filepath);
args.Request.Data.SetStorageItems(new[] { file } );
```

I've also tried:

```
string filepath = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Pictures\\pic.png";
string filepath = @"C:\Users\USER\Pictures\pic.png";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with below code:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(installedLocation.Path + @"/Assets/Configuration/Menu.xml");
```

Answer (score 4):

In WinRT, you can't directly reference a file using its name. Folders that a Windows Store app can use are limited and can be accessed only using the proper API. You can find a list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx.

In particular, because you're trying to access to a picture in the Pictures folder, you need to use the **KnownFolders.PictureLibrary** location. You also need to declare the relative capability. Take a look to this article for more information: http://danlb.blogspot.it/2011/11/winrt-file-access.html.

Comment: I have declared the capability, so I can open files using the filepath, this problem popped up in Share. With KnownFolders.PictureLibrary how is that string declaration go, could you give me an example?